# Alternative to using __file__ find the binary folder in my python package

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, packaging, pyoxidizer

I published a library to PyPI ('nmrsim') that has the following structure (edited to only include the relevant files/folders):

```
nmrsim
├── nmrsim
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── T1.npz
│   │   ⋮
│   │   └── T11.npz
│   | 
│   └── qm.py
│   
└── tests
    └── test_qm.py
```

The `bin` directory contains binaries (sparse matrices of partial solutions) for faster calculations. For `qm.py` to discover the `bin` directory regardless of where it's installed and called from (e.g. an end user's main app, the module's test suite `tests/test_qm.py`, an IDE...), references to `__file__` are used, e.g. in `qm.py`:

```
def _tm_cache(nspins):
    filename = f'T{nspins}.npz'
    bin_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bin')
    path = os.path.join(bin_dir, filename)
    try:
        T_sparse = sparse.load_npz(path)
        return T_sparse
    except FileNotFoundError:
        <work around missing file>
```

The library can be successfully pip-installed and used across platforms. However, using PyInstaller to create a 1-file frozen app fails because the `bin` directory isn't included. Looking through documentation for PyInstaller and PyOxidizer (a possible alernative), it seems that the use of **file** is problematic for "freezing" python apps.

How might I refactor code such as this to avoid using `__file__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution:

1. Add an `__init__.py` to the `bin` folder.
2. Import the bin folder as a module, e.g. `qm.py` will have an 'import nmrsim.bin' statement.
3. Use importlib.resources.path to create a context manager object:

```
filename = f'T{nspins}.npz'
path_context = resources.path(nmrsim.bin, filename)
```

4. Consume the context manager with a "with...as" block to obtain the path:

```
with path_context as p:
    path = p
```